# how to get the key of a selected value from a dropdown in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

how to bind a json data which has a key-value pair to select html in reactjs, such that It should display the value in the drop-down and If I choose a value , I should provide the relevant key?

For example:

```
var optionsdata = [
   {key='101',value='Lion'},
   {key='102',value='Giraffe'},
   {key='103',value='Zebra'},
   {key='104',value='Hippo'},
   {key='105',value='Penguin'}
  ];
```

in the drop-down, it should show "Lion","Giraffe","Zebra",...
if I choose, Zebra, I should get the select value (Zebra) as well as the key (103, in the above example)

Comment: Because you have the `optionsData`, why don't you match it with the selected value to get the key?

Comment: @Khang , that will work, but how will we handle duplicate entries in this case? For example if we have student name and student-id (key), two student can have same name

Comment: the `key` is unique right? then you could the `key` to be `value` of option, like this: `<option value={prop.key}>{prop.value}</option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply `filter` out the data from the your object once you get get the value of selected option. I have not used controlled input in my example, If you use that it will be even better.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      optionsdata : [
         {key:'101',value:'Lion'},
         {key:'102',value:'Giraffe'},
         {key:'103',value:'Zebra'},
         {key:'104',value:'Hippo'},
         {key:'105',value:'Penguin'}
       ]
    }
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    var value = this.state.optionsdata.filter(function(item) {
      return item.key == e.target.value
    })
    console.log(value[0].value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.optionsdata.map(function(data, key){  return (
          <option key={key} value={data.key}>{data.value}</option> )
        })}
      </select>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How will we handle duplicate entries in this case? For example if we have student name and student-id (key), two student can have same name

Comment: Yeah you were right, I changed the code to include the value attribute to be the key as this will be unique. we can then find the corresponding value from this key attribute

Answer (score 4):

Hope this answer will help

**1) First find selected index which is called key**

```
var selectedIndex = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
```

**2) If you have custom attribute and want to fetch value of that attribute then**

```
var customAtrribute= event.target.options[selectedIndex].getAttribute('customAtrribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select). It is able to handle `id` and `value` elegantly. Map your `id` to react-select `value` and your `value` to react-select `label`.

You can configure callback which will return you selected value/s. You can even turn on search.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a dropdown list from an object, you can map the object inside the "Select" tag in your JSX: (the 'my0bject' variable is actually a list of objects)

```
<select onChange={getValue}>
    {my0bject.map(x=><option key={x._id} data-id={x._id}>{x.name}</option>)}
</select>
```

The "key" attribute is only for react, you cannot access it later when you want to retrieve the id, so you need to create another custom attribute.

When you want to get the value:

```
function getValue(e) {
    const idChosen = e.target.children[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
}
```